# linkedin access token oauth_expires_in VS 60 days expiration

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication (section: Refreshing Access Tokens)

The paragraph says

> LinkedIn access token can be refreshed in 60 days time

on the other hand it also says that client application can keep track of token creation date and compare it with `oauth_expires_in value` (in seconds) and refresh token if required.

However, I get only `oauth_expires_in=599` (secs) when I call request token endpoint.

When I retrieve request token:
`oauth_token=xxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&xoauth_request_auth_url=https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize&`, here's a response that I get: `oauth_expires_in=599`

I do not receive such parameter in response to access token request:
`https[://]www[.]linkedin[.]com/uas/oauth/authorize/submit?oauth_token=xxx&oauth_verifier=xxx`

Can someone please explain this?

P.S.: Altered urls with [] because it didnt allow me to post more than 2 urls due to lack of reputation.

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expiry time you're getting in seconds is the expiry time for the requestToken, not the accessToken. In other words, if you don't exchange that token with an access token in the next 599 seconds (10 minutes) , it will expire and you will need to get a new requestToken.

The oauth token you receive has an expiry date of 60 days, per linkedin documentation. I hope this helps.